# Magento getStoreConfig multistore

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've tried to get the config i created in admin, this's the core_config_data table

```
|config_id|scope   |scope_id|path                            |value|
|123      |websites|2       |myappgeneral/current_time/second|3600 |
|124      |websites|3       |myappgeneral/current_time/second|7200 |
|125      |websites|4       |myappgeneral/current_time/second|1800 |
```

I have 1 page to show all info like this

Website **2** will be started in **3600** seconds

Website **3** will be started in **7200** seconds

Website **4** will be started in **1800** seconds

How can i get the values?
thks

Comment: i use query `SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE "myappgeneral/current_time/second"`
can use it to get value?if can, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use

```
Mage::app()->getWebsite($website_id)
    ->getConfig('myappgeneral/current_time/second')
```

The $website_id parameter is optional, by default current website used.

But normally you need a storeview value, which you can retrieve using

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('myappgeneral/current_time/second', $store_id)
```

The $store_id parameter is optional and may contain store view id or store view code, by default current store view used.

More info here - http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration, section "Retrieving Values"